# How to search product by field in different table

Tags: python, odoo

I want to use name_search in product to get product by search the lot name which in `stock.production.lot`

`relation stock_quant_ids,product_id,lot_id`

```
class ProductProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    @api.model
    def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):

        args = args or []
        print('arg ',args)
        recs = self.search([('???', operator, name)]  args, limit=limit) #stock_quant_ids.lot_id.name
        print('recs ', recs)
        if not recs.ids:
            return super(ProductProduct, self).name_search(name=name, args=args,
                                                       operator=operator,
                                                       limit=limit)
        return recs.name_get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    """ search for product using the Lot number """
    args = args or []
    recs = None
    # only perform search by when the name is passed
    if name:
        # don't use limit here
        recs = self.env['stock.production.lot'].search([('name', operator, name)])

    if recs:
        # handle extra filter that was passed by the domain attribute in the XML
        args = expression.AND([args, [('id', 'in', recs.mapped('product_id').ids)]])
        return self.search(args, limit=limit).name_get()

    # no Lot was founded may be the user meant to search by product name
    return super(ProductProduct, self).name_search(name=name,
                                            args=args,
                                            operator=operator,
                                            limit=limit)
```

Comment: In first code it gives me all products , second code doesn't return any product. first code work when i replace recs.mapped('product_id').name_get() with recs.mapped('product_id').name_get()

Comment: Sorry about syntax errors I didn't try the code, check my updates I used `OR` instead of `AND` that's why you where getting all product, here is a better method, to handle your requirement. the problem here this behavior will be in all of your many2one field do you really want to do this. if you don't use context to apply this method method only the a context have a special key, if you don't know how tell me and I let know how.

Comment: can i pass this lot name to prod_lot_id  ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: now we enter lot name in (stock.inventory.line) we get product name , we still need to choose the lot from many2one (prod_lot_id) , this scenario from Inventory Adjustments .

Comment: you sill need to search for lot when you select a product, but you can search for lot first then automatically select the product by onchange event. You want when you search for product by lot name to automatically select that lot, I don't think this is possible. just post another question to explain what you need exactly it's better

Comment: where is onchange ?

Comment: It's better if you ask another question and explain the sinario that you need, you will get help I didn't understand what you are asking me thanks